# Limit of a volterra equation

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, integral-equations

Let's say : $$\lim_{s\to 0} f(s) = C$$ Does the following limit of a Volterra integral holds?

\begin{equation}
\lim_{T\to 0} \int_0^T f(s) K(s,T) ds = C \lim_{T \to 0} \int_0^T K(s,T)ds 
\end{equation}

Where $K(s,T)$ is well defined and finite.

Can anyone explain whether this relationship holds, if so, what is the "name" or lemma of this kind of relationship?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that $K$ is well defined and finite? Will this imply that $K$ is bounded on $[0,T]^2$ for any $T >0$?

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín you can view $K(s,T)=(T-s)^\alpha$ where $0.5<\alpha<1$. So, in other words, i am asking like is it possible for the relationship to hold as an area with multiple of two components $C$ and the integral? I actually need to find "what does the initial integral tends to, in terms of $T$", rather than the final answer as zero.

Comment: Thanks. Well for $K(s,T):=(T-s)^\alpha$ with $\frac{1}{2}< \alpha <1$ the limit on the right hand side is always 0. Are you requiring $f$ to be continuous? If not, I think one should be able to find a non continuous $f$ such that the limit on the right hand side is not $0$.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín i am actually trying to get the asymptotical solution (in terms of T). For example $\int_0^T f(s)K(s,T) ds ~ C g(T)$ as $T \to 0$ where $g(T)$ is a function in terms of $T$. I do know the limit tends to zero, but i want the asymptotical solution, sorry for not specifying early....